# Calculate number of days in a year

Tags: apex

How to calculate Calculate number of days in a year?. In [reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_date.htm#apex_System_Date_daysInMonth) exists Date.daysInMonth but not in a year.

Comment: Can you add some more detail of your use case - is this just the number of calendar days in 1 year or number of working days? After all years are more fixed at 365 or 366 days? [ask]

Comment: You can do Date.isLeapYear(Date.Today().Year()); So you can return 365 or 366 based on true and false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do `Date.isLeapYear(someYear);` and return 365 or 366 based on if it returns true or false.

```
public static Integer daysInYear() { return daysInYear(Date.today()); }
public static Integer daysInYear(Date input)
{
    return Date.isLeapYear(input.year()) ? 366 : 365;
}
```

Comment: @AdrianLarson Go ahead.